# Helm installs charts but doesn't see them

Tags: linux, jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'v installed minikube and helm on my system run vm, and tried to deploy jenkins

```
MacBook-Pro% helm install stable/jenkins
NAME:   quelling-dachshund
Error: getting deployed release "quelling-dachshund": release: "quelling-dachshund" not found
```

Seems like an error but Kubectl can see the deployment after this error first in `Init:0/1` and then `running`- any ideas why it flops on the `install` part ?

btw:

````
$ helm list --all
Error: the server was unable to return a response in the time allotted, but may still be processing the request (get pods)```
````

```
$ helm list
Error: Get https://192.168.64.4:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods?labelSelector=app%3Dhelm%2Cname%3Dtiller: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

any idea how to resolve the error

---

Update ***
It all comes down to minikube error which I dont understand - btw. this is just after fresh `minikube start`

```
$ kubectl create serviceaccount --namespace kube-system tiller --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true
serviceaccount/tiller created
$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-rule --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/tiller-cluster-rule created
$ helm init --service-account tiller --upgrade
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /Users/rwalas/.helm.
Error: error installing: the server could not find the requested resource
$ rm -rf ~/.helm
$ helm init --service-account tiller --upgrade
Creating /Users/rwalas/.helm
Creating /Users/rwalas/.helm/repository
Creating /Users/rwalas/.helm/repository/cache
Creating /Users/rwalas/.helm/repository/local
Creating /Users/rwalas/.helm/plugins
Creating /Users/rwalas/.helm/starters
Creating /Users/rwalas/.helm/cache/archive
Creating /Users/rwalas/.helm/repository/repositories.yaml
Adding stable repo with URL: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
Adding local repo with URL: http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /Users/<user>/.helm.
Error: error installing: the server could not find the requested resource
```

Comment: Which version of Helm?  (From that command line, 2.16.x?)  Is the minikube setup otherwise healthy; can you `kubectl get pods` and see things like Tiller?

Comment: Helm is in 2.9.1 version - I changed command from the issue and then `kubectl get all` return only `service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   34s`

Comment: tbh it all comes down to some helm error - check the update above

Comment: `kubectl patch deploy --namespace kube-system tiller-deploy -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"serviceAccount":"tiller"}}}}'
` this line helped after `helm init` on fresh minikube cluster

Comment: Please. try running this `helm init --service-account tiller --override spec.selector.matchLabels.'name'='tiller',spec.selector.matchLabels.'app'='helm' --output yaml | sed 's@apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1@apiVersion: apps/v1@' | kubectl apply -f -`